# Determining the magnitude of influence between two variables

Tags: regression

I am trying to figure out the magnitude of influence one variable has over another, and how much it changes if we analyze it in the opposite direction as well. Essentially, I am trying to figure out if variable A is influencing variable B more or the other way around. I ran two simple linear regression models and got the below results though I am a little new to statistics so I'm not particularly sure how to interpret them or if this method of analysis is the correct way to tackle the issue. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Research "correlation is not causation."

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! `Essentially, I am trying to figure out if variable A is influencing variable B more or the other way around.` This makes it sound like there has to be a temporal aspect to your work, even setting aside correlation vs causation.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: With the data you seem to have, this is impossible.

Longer answer:

First, "magnitude of influence" is not a usual statistical term. What exactly do you mean?

Second, while you haven't said what data you have, it seems like you have one measurement of each variable for each subject. No repeat measures, nothing temporal. If that is correct, then there is no way, statistically, to say which way the "influence" is going or even if it's going in either direction. This is what the comments about "correlation is not causation" are alluding to.

You *may* be able to make a substantive argument that the influence goes in one direction and not the other, but, without a lot more complex data, you can't say what's happening from statistics. You would need repeat measures for both variables, and then you could do a multilevel model. But this still wouldn't really show "influence" (at least, not how I am imagining that word). For that, you'd either need an actual experiment (with randomization) or else a lot of covariates (which would only make causation more reasonable).  If you really want to get into it, there is a lot of material on causation, going back at least to Aristotle and forward at least to Judea Pearl. Neither Aristotle nor Pearl are easy to read or understand.

Third, in the output note, e.g. that the t value for the variables in the two models is exactly the same (18.21). This arises from the math behind the regression. You could make up any two variables and this would be so.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I'm not the most well-versed in statistics so I wasn't necessarily sure if the question even made sense as I presented it, but your response was very helpful.